# Check for particular files inside a directory

Tags: shell-script

I want to check directory 1 8 and 4 present inside a list of parent directory that is passed as argument to the script.
PFB my script

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

cd $line
echo "checking in $line" >> ../filesearch.log

if [ [ -d 1]  &&  [ -d 8]  &&  [ -d 4] ]; then
echo "1 8 4 exists" >> ../filesearch.log
else
    echo "Dir 1 8 4 does not exist" >> ../filesearch.log
fi
cd ../

done < "$1"
```

I am getting the below error when i use if [ [ -d 1]  &&  [ -d 8]  &&  [ -d 4] ];

```
 ./fs.sh: line 8: [: -d: binary operator expected
```

if we use [[ -d  1 ]]; instead of if [ [ -d 1]  &&  [ -d 8]  &&  [ -d 4] ]; my code is working fine but my requirement is to check for all the above mentioned files(1 4 8) are present in the parent directory or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this `if [ -d 1 ] && [ -d 8 ] && [ -d 4 ]`

edit: disregard, the answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Your underlying problem here is that you assume that `[` is just same kind of parentheses, and that you can nest them. That is not true. The expression `[ ... ]` is the same as `test ...`.

The `test` utility has the possibility to combine multiple test with `-a` for `and` and with `-o` for `or`. See the manual for details.

So you can write your check as `test -d 1 -a d 4 -a -d 8` or `[ -d 1 -a d 4 -a -d 8 ]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if [[ -d 1 && -d 8 && -d 4 ]];
```